# Manually trigger a teamcity build from github

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity, devops

I want to trigger a build in Teamcity by doing a manual action(not a commit or pullrequests). Like if i click a button in github it should trigger a build config in teamcity or something similar(by passing the branch). I dont want the process to be automatic for every commits, instead just manually trigger for custom branches.

If there is a possibility for this, pls let me know as it would be much helpfull..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by leaving your Triggers menu empty...
[image]
Go to Build --> Edit settings --> Triggers and make shore that there are no triggers. You can alway manually run build by clicking on icon RUN
[image]

If you want trigger just for couple of branches you can add trigger to your VCS like this
[image]

so my list contains branches develop, qa, release and master and rule +:*/merge is for every open Pull Request